# 3 select changes the parameters of the url

Tags: javascript, html, select

In my web page I have 3 selects and I need to make sure that when the value inside each select changes, the parameters that make up a url in the href change.

this is the html code of the select:

```
<select id="comune" name="comune">
 <option value="">Comune</option>
 <option value="comune1">comune 1</option>
 <option value="comune2">comune 2</option>
 <option value="comune3">comune 3</option>
</select>

<select id="nome" name="nome">
 <option value="">Nome</option>
 <option value="nome1">nome 1</option>
 <option value="nome2">nome 2</option>
 <option value="nome3">nome 3</option>
</select>

<select id="eta" name="eta">
 <option value="">Nome</option>
 <option value="eta1">eta 1</option>
 <option value="eta2">eta 2</option>
 <option value="eta3">eta 3</option>
</select>

<a href="elenco-mappa.html?comune=&nome=&eta=" id="cerca">cerca</a>
```

this is the code in js that i am integrating, but i don't know how to put the other parameters:

```
$("#comune").change(function () {
 console.log(this.value);
 $("#cerca").attr('href', '/elenco-mappa.html?comune=' + this.value);
});
```

thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this What you want?

```
<select id="comune" name="comune">
 <option value="">Comune</option>
 <option value="comune1">comune 1</option>
 <option value="comune2">comune 2</option>
 <option value="comune3">comune 3</option>
</select>

<select id="nome" name="nome">
 <option value="">Nome</option>
 <option value="nome1">nome 1</option>
 <option value="nome2">nome 2</option>
 <option value="nome3">nome 3</option>
</select>

<select id="eta" name="eta">
 <option value="">Nome</option>
 <option value="eta1">eta 1</option>
 <option value="eta2">eta 2</option>
 <option value="eta3">eta 3</option>
</select>

<a href="elenco-mappa.html?comune=&nome=&eta=" id="cerca">cerca</a>
```

```
$("#comune, #nome, #eta").on("change", function () {

    var comune = encodeURIComponent($("#comune").val());
    var nome = encodeURIComponent($("#nome").val());
    var eta = encodeURIComponent($("#eta").val());

    var link = `elenco-mappa.html?comune=${comune}&nome=${nome}&eta=${eta}`;
    $("#cerca").attr("href", link);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need an event listener for each select. The function can be the same for all three select. You can see a working snippet below:

```js
   const comune = document.getElementById('comune');
   const nome = document.getElementById('nome');
   const eta = document.getElementById('eta');
   const cerca = document.getElementById('cerca');

   function generateLink() {
     cerca.href = `elenco-mappa.html?comune=${comune.value}&nome=${nome.value}&eta=${eta.value}`;
     console.log(cerca.href);
   }
   
   comune.addEventListener('change', generateLink);
   nome.addEventListener('change', generateLink);
   eta.addEventListener('change', generateLink);
```

```html
<select id="comune" name="comune">
  <option value="">Comune</option>
  <option value="comune1">comune 1</option>
  <option value="comune2">comune 2</option>
  <option value="comune3">comune 3</option>
 </select>
 
 <select id="nome" name="nome">
  <option value="">Nome</option>
  <option value="nome1">nome 1</option>
  <option value="nome2">nome 2</option>
  <option value="nome3">nome 3</option>
 </select>
 
 <select id="eta" name="eta">
  <option value="">Nome</option>
  <option value="eta1">eta 1</option>
  <option value="eta2">eta 2</option>
  <option value="eta3">eta 3</option>
 </select>
 
 <a href="elenco-mappa.html?comune=&nome=&eta=" id="cerca">cerca</a>
```

I put a console.log to show you the result, but of course you should remove it

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prams = {
                comune :'',
                nome : '',
                eta : ''
            }

           $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.select').change(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                var val = $(this).val();

                prams[name] = val;

                $('#cerca').attr('href',`elenco-mappa.html?comune=${prams.comune}&nome${prams.nome}=&eta=${prams.eta}`);

            });
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <select id="comune" name="comune" class="select">
            <option value="">Comune</option>
            <option value="comune1">comune 1</option>
            <option value="comune2">comune 2</option>
            <option value="comune3">comune 3</option>
        </select>

        <select id="nome" name="nome" class="select">
            <option value="">Nome</option>
            <option value="nome1">nome 1</option>
            <option value="nome2">nome 2</option>
            <option value="nome3">nome 3</option>
        </select>

        <select id="eta" name="eta" class="select">
            <option value="">Nome</option>
            <option value="eta1">eta 1</option>
            <option value="eta2">eta 2</option>
            <option value="eta3">eta 3</option>
        </select>

        <a href="elenco-mappa.html?comune=&nome=&eta=" id="cerca">cerca</a>
```